# Hilbert scheme of two points of affine n space

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I believe that an answer to the following is known but was unable to find it anywhere.

**What is $\operatorname{Hilb}^2(\mathbb A^n)$?**

Of course, $\operatorname{Hilb}^2(\mathbb A^1)\cong\mathbb A^2$ and $\operatorname{Hilb}^2(\mathbb A^2)\cong\mathbb A^4$, so I was thinking that probably $\operatorname{Hilb}^2(\mathbb A^n)=\mathbb A^{2n}$ could be true but I was unable to find a reference. It would be nice if someone could provide me with the answer + reference.

Comment: Are you sure for your description ? If I'm not mistaken $Hilb^2(A^2)$ is the blow up of $Sym^2(A^2)$ along the diagonal, in particular it contains (many) copies of $\Bbb P^1$ which is not the case of $\Bbb A^4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each $n$ there is a natural map 
$$
Hilb^2(\mathbb{A}^n) \to Gr(2,n+1) \setminus Gr(2,n)
$$
that takes a subscheme to the unique line supporting it (considered as a line in $\mathbb{P}^n$ that is not contained in $\mathbb{P}^{n-1} = \mathbb{P}^n \setminus \mathbb{A}^n$). All fibers of this map can be identified with $Hilb^2(\mathbb{A}^1) = \mathbb{A}^2$. Moreover this map is a locally trivial vector bundle (the restriction of the symmetric square of the tautological bundle from the Grassmannian). In particular, it is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{A}^{2n}$ for $n \ge 2$ (even for $n = 2$!).

Comment: Thus, $\operatorname{Hilb}^2(\mathbb A^n)$ is (the total space of) an (algebraically? analytically?) locally trivial fibre bundle over an open subset of the Grassmannian with fibres $\mathbb A^2$ and over a trivializing open subset of the Grassmannian it looks like $\mathbb A^n$ if I counted dimensions correctly?

Comment: It is algebraically locally trivial. Over the open Schubert cell of the Grassmannian (which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{A}^n$ it is even a trivial $\mathbb{A}^n$-fibration, thus it contains $\mathbb{A}^{2n}$ as an open subset.

Comment: Nice description. Is there some reference where I can read about this?

Comment: If I consider $Hilb^2(\mathbb P^n)$, the map $x\mapsto \langle x\rangle$ goes to all of the Grassmannian, correct? Thus, arguing as you did, $Hilb^2(\mathbb P^n)\to Gr(2,n+1)$ is a locally trivial algebraic fibre bundle with fibre $\mathbb P^2$ if am not mistaken.

Comment: That's right. It is identified with the projectivization of the symmetric square of the tautological bundle.